Confusing Angular behaviour in *ngFor loop
I'm a bit confused over the behaviour of this loop in Angular:
A simple *ngFor loop over an array of 5 fields
<div *ngFor="let field of this.fields" >
  <div class="block">{{ field.title }} : {{getValue(field)}}</div>
</div>

The function getValue is
getValue(field) {
    console.log("getValue: "+ this._counter++, field.title);
    return field.name;
}

Given that the array is just 5 fields I would expect the function getValue to execute only 5 times (or the number of items in the array) but as you can see from this fiddle it executes 20 times when run first, and any change in state makes it run 10 more times. (read from the console)
In fact an array with just 1 item will run 4 times when the page loads and any change of state will cause it to run twice.
This becomes more pronounced in a proper application with an array of hundreds and a complex function that runs to get the data.
This appears to be the same for all versions of Angular (at least the ones I've tested from v4-v16)
So I was wondering. first of all why this executes so many times, and secondly is there a more efficient way to loop through the array given that there is a complex function to return the data?

you shouldn't use function calls in angular template cause they will be executed every time angular detects some changes, so it is executed if we move our cursor around the screen or whatever event we want to mention since it triggers a change detection in the component. A workaround may be to iterate the array in the ts file and add a new key to use in the template right after.

Each time you write a function into an interpolation in .html, Angular should execute each time to know if "some has changed".
When you use a variable Angular compare the value of the variable with the old value of it, but if you use a fuinction Angular should execute the function to get the actual value.
You can minimize using ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush (this have more implications, and be sure understands before use or not).
Equals happens if you write a simple
{{getValue()}}

getValue()
{
   return "hello word"
}

In general it's the reason we we should avoid use functions in .html even more when we have a loop. In case of an array you can write some like
this.fieldsExtends=this.fields.map(x=>({...x,value:this.getValue(x)}))

and you can iterate over fieldExtends
<!--NOTE: in .html remove the "this", the only variables that you can show
    are the public variables of your component-->

<div *ngFor="let field of fieldsExtends" >
  <div class="block">{{ field.title }} : field.value}</div>
</div>



Change detection runs twice in development server, so maybe that attributes why 10 became 20.

Change detection ran before the view is initialized, this might attribute for the first 10 records!

After this change detection again run so that attributes for the remaining 10 records

When you add a row into the array, there is a possibility that the data inside each of the array elements has changed so  change detection runs for each of the get methods!


code
ngDoCheck
main.ts:37 getValue: 0 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 1 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 2 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 3 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 4 test
main.ts:42 ngAfterViewInit
main.ts:37 getValue: 5 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 6 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 7 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 8 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 9 test
chunk-7ESZLVZO.js?v=76da9c7e:19762 Angular is running in development mode.
main.ts:50 ngDoCheck
main.ts:37 getValue: 10 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 11 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 12 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 13 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 14 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 15 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 16 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 17 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 18 test
main.ts:37 getValue: 19 test

Stackblitz
If you ask if there is a better way, yes, Signals can be used to remedy this. You can use computed to perform complex calculations that will be validated only when the root signal has changed, so it's more fine-grained control and requires change detection to run fewer times, hence higher performance.
This is my understanding of Signals and change detection, take it with a grain of salt :)
